# Latest Karmic Ubuntu update broke system

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, updates

Today I installed updates for my ubuntu and there were some problems. It said that it can't do everything, but there was an option to continue. It wanted to remove a lot of packages and during that work it stoped with error. After reboot there wasn't any kernel in /boot ! Only memtest is there.

How can I fix it? I booted from Live CD (but version 9.04), is there a way to run update of system installed on disk? Probably there are many missing packages.

Answer (score 1):

Boot from a Live-CD, chroot into your installation ([here is a nice how-to](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=24575)) and reinstall the kernel.

Comment: Thanks! It took me almost 2 hours, but finally it is working! Apart of reinstaling kernel, I also had to install about 50 packages by hand... Very strange update... Hope it won't happen again. I've asked this question without login, so I don't know how to accept it.

Comment: @klew: I think this was a mix of bad circumstances...but to determine that we'd need to know what exact messages you got. ;) But I don't think it will happen again. Also, don't forget to accept my answer if it answered your question. ;)

Comment: I'd love to accept your question, but I don't know how. I asked this question without login in. According to my messages. It wasn't very clear. It was running standard ubuntu update and showed some window with information that only part of updates can be done. And then it said that skype package is conflicting and it didn't do any update. So I removed skype and accept to proced with partial update. It showed my big list of packages to uninstall and I accepted it ;). It took few minutes to do it and there was an error like "I can't install update" (almost meaningless ;)). And that's it.

Comment: I can share some logs, but tell me which one :)

Comment: @klew: Not necessary if it's working again, but for the future. ;) Nearly every problem which starts like "my system won't boot" or "this program crashes all the time" will get a comment like "what do the logs say" or "start the program from a terminal and show us the output". ;)